# Is it bad to run a processor at above 90% for long periods?

Tags: cpu

I have a Celeron N2840 in a 7yo Lenovo laptop. As a senior high school student, I need to run medium-heavy apps like MS Teams, Python and sometimes Android Studio. I've noticed that the CPU runs at about 90% constantly, while the 8Gigs of RAM have no problem. Would like to know if it is a threat when I run my laptop for about 8-10hrs straight a day, every week. The laptop has pretty much 0 cooling because of it being old.

Comment: _"The laptop has pretty much 0 cooling because of it being old"_ - I don't see how that's related?

Comment: I've deleted the product recommendation request because [these are off-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Open it up and clean the fans, replace thermal pads and so on. If it works then it works and we can't say how long for.